# Is this video by Carl Sagan?

Tags: astronomy, video, carl-sagan

I found a video a video on youtube :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ugyrzr5Ds8o

Carl Segan on Hindu Civilization,
Can anyone confirm if this footage is really from Carl Sagan?

Comment: Voting to close: This is simply too trivial. A Google of either "Carl Sagan Hindu" or "Carl Sagan Vedic" (as in the video's title) basically gives you the answer. Carl Sagan's Wiki or a Google of "Carl Sagan Cosmos" points to the book and TV series.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's an episode of [Cosmos: A Personal Voyage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos:_A_Personal_Voyage) by Carl Sagan.

> Cosmos: A Personal Voyage is a thirteen-part television series written by Carl Sagan, Ann Druyan, and Steven Soter, with Sagan as presenter.

That video is a part of episode 10: "[The Edge of Forever](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0760462/?ref_=ttep_ep10)"

A copy of that episode can be [found on DailyMotion](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1h5ogx_carl-sagan-s-cosmos-e10-the-edge-of-forever_tv), and that clip starts at 34m50s.

Please note: the cosmology in the video is a bit dated (the episode is 35 years old!)